# Simple jQuery Animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-animate, fade

I've posted similar question but no response.

I have a jQuery Mobile site and I need a simple animation in my header.

See my JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/twGHC/39/

I have a logo in my header which is `width:284px; height:58px;` and it's a 1px Transparent GIF - being replaced with a background image.

My background image contains the two slides that I need a cycle fade on.

I need the logo to cycle (fade in/out) between these 2 css rules on my image:

```
div#header-logo a img {
    background-position: top;
}
```

and

```
div#header-logo a img {
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

I think the jquery css property is `{ backgroundPosition, 'bottom' }` and `{ backgroundPosition, 'top' }`

Each slide can be shown for 2seconds before cycling.

Can someone tell me if this is possible just using jQuery Mobile? and not having to introduce a new plugin. Trying to keep this as light as possible with a function.

Any help would be amazing thanks!

My HTML

```
<div id="header-logo">

     <a href="#home" data-direction="reverse">
          <img src="x.gif" alt="" style="width:284px;height:58px;" />
     </a>    

</div>
```

My CSS

```
div#header-logo {
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin: 14px auto 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 282px;
    height: 73px;
}

div#header-logo a img {
    width: 284px;
    height: 58px;
    background-image: url('http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/85137.png');
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-position: top;
    background-color: red;
}
```

See my JSfiddle here if you want to experiement... http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/twGHC/39/

UPDATE: First idea seems to work fine, thanks Andy! See here.. http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/twGHC/40/

Can it get any lighter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about positioning a clone of the image, with the clone having `background-position: bottom` set and then a 2 second interval to [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) the `opacity` of each image? Might not be the *cleanest* way to do it but dropping this code into your fiddle works for me in Chrome 14 without any other CSS or HTML changes.

```
var anchor = $('div#header-logo a');
var img = anchor.find('img');
var position = img.position();
var bottom = img.clone();
bottom.css({position:'absolute',top:position.top,backgroundPosition:'bottom','opacity':0});
$('div#header-logo a').append(bottom);

var cycleHeader = setInterval(function(){
    img.animate({'opacity':img.css('opacity') == 0 ? 1 : 0});
    bottom.animate({'opacity':bottom.css('opacity') == 0 ? 1 : 0});
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Hi Andyb, seems to do the trick good.

Nice and light, thank you for your time on this!!!

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/twGHC/40/